# How to test if an imported ES6 function is called on useEffect inside the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs

I'm trying to create a simple test in Jest that should check if an imported function is called inside *useEffect* in the component's lifecycle.

**index.js**

```
import { myFunc } from './myFunctions';


const myComponent = () => {

   useEffect(() => {
      myFunc()
   }, [])

   return ()
}

 export default MyComponent
```

And now I want to create a test `index.test.js` file to test if that *myFunc* was called one time. I've got a special function that renders the mocked component (it's called *prepare()*).

**index.test.js**

```
import * as myFunctions from './myFunctions';

describe('when the component renders', () => {

   it('the function should be called once', () => {

       const spy = jest.spyOn(myFunctions, 'myFunc');
       prepare(); // Function rendering myComponent
       expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

**myFunctions.js**

```
export const myFunc = () => {

   doSomething()

}

...
```

**My error**

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

Comment: Add some logging capabilities on your own, check on your local instance and then you'll know. If you are not sure with your test suite if the method works, then consider tests for the method itself, cause apparently you are in wrong place to test that method.

Comment: For instance: if the result of that method is reflecting on UI, you can check if that result is visible on UI. But if doesn't affect UI, then consider unit test for that method separately.

Comment: @pkolawa the problem is that it doesn't affect UI at all. I am 100% sure that my method works as it impacts (add an object into) the window.dataLayer. And still I can't find any solution to that.

Comment: According to your snippets there's case-sensitive issue, exporting MyComponent, while component itself is named myComponent - JS is case-sensitive, but I guess it's not the case

Comment: Are you sure that component is rendered on a moment when spy is checked? I mean: preapre() method is fully executed and component is fully ready?

Comment: As far as I understand, I think it's fully executed. I believe the problem lays in the fact that I can't spy on functions wrapped within useEffect, however, I have no idea how to handle that.